# android programing code error for google placepicker Api

Tags: android

```
    get_places = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    get_places.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

            Intent intent;
            try {
                intent = builder.build((Activity) getApplicationContext());
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

when i debug the application it shows the error below

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to android.app.Activity   at
>   com.example.kalii.locate.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part:

```
(Activity) getApplicationContext()
```

Application context is never of type `Activity` but rather of type `Application`. You need to provide a reference to an activity for the build method, for example

```
intent = builder.build(YourActivity.this);
```

If you're calling from inside the activity (you need to provide outer class reference, hence `YourActivity.this`, of course replace the name with the actual class name of your activity),

```
intent = builder.build(getActivity());
```

If you're calling from inside the fragment, etc.

Comment: thanks for the help. but am still getting the error when i try to use (this or getActivity()).

Comment: Since the call to builder is inside the `OnClickListener`, you have to provide reference to the outer Activity class. See edited answer.

Comment: thank you it has worked perfectly by using (this) key word.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept and upvote my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
intent = builder.build((Activity) getApplicationContext());
```

getApplicationContext() returns application context of type Context whose super class is Application so inside any method or anonymous class use-

```
ActivityName.this
```